# Userscript,vk bot ввод значений в chat input

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]**Пишу vk бота,нужно вписать в chat input число '5000'.**

```
var sr = document.getElementById('im_editable2000000017');
    sr.setAttribute="5000"
```

Выдавало ошибку

> Cannot set property 'setAttribute' of null

Не сколько раз обновлял страницу и заметил что id textboxa меняется. Пробовал

```
var sr = document.getElementById('im_editable2000000017',im_editable0);
        sr.setAttribute="5000"
```

Больше ошибок нету но значение так и не устанавливается в textbox.
Возможно ли вообще такое решение?Если да то в чем ошибка?
Только учу js.Заранее спасибо.
Мой код полностью:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         script
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  try to take over the world!
// @author       You
// @match        https://vk.com/im?sel=c17
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    function inp() {
        var sr = document.getElementById('im_editable2000000017');
        sr.value = "5000"; // Записываем значение в input
    }
    inp();

})();
```

```html
<div class="im_editable im-chat-input--text _im_text" tabindex="0" contenteditable="true" id="im_editable200000001754" role="textbox" aria-multiline="true"></div>
<div class="composer_wdd clear_fix wdd_toup" id="im_editable200000001790" style="">
  <div class="wdd_lwrap" style="display: none; width: auto;">
    <div class="wdd_list"></div>
  </div><input type="hidden" id="'im_editable2000000017'" value="false">
  <input type="hidden" id="im_editable200000001712" value="false">
</div>
<script language="JavaScript">
  var sr = document.getElementById('im_editable200000001712');
  sr.value = "5000"; // Записываем значение в input
</script>
```

Comment: Ну так Вы имя атрибута сначала задайте.

Comment: @Denis640Kb,задал,результат такой же.

Answer (score 0):

Если Вы хотите задать именно атрибут, то надо сначала задать ему имя:

```js
    var sr = document.getElementById('im_editable2000000017');
    sr.setAttribute('Blink', "5000"); // Записываем значение атрибута.       console.log(document.getElementById('im_editable2000000017').getAttribute("Blink")); // Получаем значение атрибута
```

```html
<input id="im_editable2000000017">
```

Если хотите именно вписать в input значение, то надо делать по-другому:

```js
    var sr = document.getElementById('im_editable2000000017');
    sr.value = "5000"; // Записываем значение в input
```

```html
<input id="im_editable2000000017">

<script language="JavaScript">
    var sr = document.getElementById('im_editable2000000017');
    sr.value = "5000"; // Записываем значение в input
</script>
```

Пример с атрибутом:

```js
    window.onload = function () {
        var sr = document.getElementById('im_editable200000001712');
        sr.setAttribute('type', ""); // изменить атрибут
        //sr.removeAttribute('type'); // или удалить атрибут
        sr.value = "5000";
    };
```

```html
<div class="im_editable im-chat-input--text _im_text" tabindex="0" contenteditable="true" id="im_editable200000001754" role="textbox" aria-multiline="true"></div>
<div class="composer_wdd clear_fix wdd_toup" id="im_editable200000001790" style="">
    <div class="wdd_lwrap" style="display: none; width: auto;">
        <div class="wdd_list"></div>
    </div><input type="hidden" id="'im_editable2000000017'" value="false">
    <input type="hidden" id="im_editable200000001712" value="false">
</div>
```

Comment: Ошибки не выдает,но все так-же не вписало значение в input

Comment: @Egor Shutyaev Посмотрите, пожалуйста, пример и попробуйте его запустить тут в сниппете. Пример рабочий. Видимо, у Вас не совсем корректно настроены данные `js`. Добавьте полностью Ваш код, чтобы можно было воспроизвести конкретно Вашу проблему.

Comment: Добавил сниппет,и полностью код,в сниппете тоже не работает

Comment: @Egor Shutyaev В Вашем случае были установлены аттрибуты `hidden` для полей. Добавил в ответ пример с изменением.

Comment: Execution of script 'sc' failed! Cannot set property 'hidden' of null.

Comment: @EgorShutaev, Да, извиняюсь, надо верхнюю строчку удалить. делал для проверки. Попробуйте сейчас.

Comment: У меня поверх chat inpu`a создалось поле input,скрин в вопросе

Comment: ,извиняюсь,уже добавил

Comment: @Egorshutaev Добавьте, пожалуйста, тогда больше кода. Или полностью выложите на codepen.io

Comment: Я могу выложить код на codepen,но полностью страница чата из 'vk.com'но код всей html страницы будет огромным.Если вы об этом.Код скрипта уже полностью написан в вопросе.

Comment: @EgorShutaev Вы в вопросе спросили как вставить значение в поле. Я показал Вам несколько примеров, как можно вставить значение в элемент.  Без полной информации просто невозможно сказать какие именно css там подключены и как обрабатывается визуально это поле.

Answer (score 0):

Я конечно не уверен, но может у вас скрипт tampermonkey отрабатывает быстрее чем загружается html? Попробуйте в верху к своим директивам добавить ещё одну: // @run-at document-end. А весь ваш код поместите сюда:

```js
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
 // Ваш код
});
```

При этом убрав самовызывающуюся функцию